# Why does the trigger always read my if statement as null?

Tags: apex, trigger, null, if

See the code below from an APEX trigger. For some reason, my trigger always reads nextRenewalDate (field from `Account` object) as `null`, regardless of whether or not it is blank. Racking my brain here and can't find a solution online. Help!

```
trigger updateCloseDate on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    for (Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

        // New variable referencing the related Account field'Next Renewal Date' 
        Date nextRenewalDate = newOpp.Account.Next_Renewal_Date__c;

        if (newOpp.RecordTypeId == '<<recordID>>') {

            // if the related Account "Next Renewal Field" is not blank
            if (nextRenewalDate == null) {
                newOpp.CloseDate = date.today() + 60;                              
            }
            if (nextRenewalDate != null) {
                newOpp.CloseDate = nextRenewalDate - 60;
            }
            break;
        }   

    }

}
```

Adding the updated code here (still not working properly):

```
trigger closeDateTest on Opportunity (before insert) {
Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();

Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){
    parentAccountIds.add(opp.AccountId);

    system.debug('parentAccountId assigned');

    //query fields on parent accounts and map them by Account Id
    Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
        select Id, Next_Renewal_Date__c
        from Account
        where Id in :parentAccountIds
        ]); 

    system.debug('SOQL Query completed');

    if(String.isNotBlank(newOpp.AccountId)) {
        Date nextRenewalDate = parentAccountsById.get(newOpp.AccountId).Next_Renewal_Date__c;

        system.debug('nextRenewalDate assigned');

        // if the Opportunity Record ID is 'New to Blue'
        if (newOpp.RecordTypeId == SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()
.get('New_to_Blue').getRecordTypeId()) {

            system.debug('checked record type');

            // if the related Account "Next Renewal Field" is not blank
            if (nextRenewalDate == null) {

                // add 60 days to Close Date
                newOpp.CloseDate = date.today() + 60; 
                newOpp.NextStep = 'is BLANK';
            }

            if (nextRenewalDate != null) {
                // subtract 60 days from Next Renewal Date
                newOpp.CloseDate = nextRenewalDate - 60;
                newOpp.NextStep = 'is FILLED IN';
            }

        } 

    }

}
```

}

THE SOLUTION:

```
trigger closeDateTest on Opportunity (before insert) {
    Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();

    Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){
        parentAccountIds.add(opp.AccountId);

        //query fields on parent accounts and map them by Account Id
        Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
            select Id, Next_Renewal_Date__c
            from Account
            where Id in :parentAccountIds
        ]); 

        for (Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {

            if(String.isNotBlank(newOpp.AccountId)) {
                Date nextRenewalDate = parentAccountsById.get(newOpp.AccountId).Next_Renewal_Date__c;

                // if the Opportunity Record ID is 'New to Blue'
                if (newOpp.RecordTypeId == SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()
    .get('New_to_Blue').getRecordTypeId()) {

                    system.debug('checked record type');

                    // if the related Account "Next Renewal Field" is not blank
                    if (nextRenewalDate == null) {

                        // add 60 days to Close Date
                        newOpp.CloseDate = date.today() + 60; 
                    }

                    if (nextRenewalDate != null) {
                        // subtract 60 days from Next Renewal Date
                        newOpp.CloseDate = nextRenewalDate - 60;
                    }

                } 

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Found the solution with a some help from @Oleksandr. His solution is not correct but it helped quite a bit. Giving him a an upvote and posting the solution to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because parent fields are not accessible in trigger context. You have to explicitly query `newOpp.Account.Next_Renewal_Date__c` field.

```
trigger updateCloseDate on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

    Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){
        parentAccountIds.add(opp.AccountId);
    }

    //query fields on parent accounts and map them by Account Id
    Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
        select Id, Next_Renewal_Date__c
        from Account
        where Id in :parentAccountIds
        ]);

    for (Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

        // New variable referencing the related Account field'Next Renewal Date' 
        if(String.isNotBlank(newOpp.AccountId)){
            Date nextRenewalDate = parentAccountsById.get(newOpp.AccountId).Next_Renewal_Date__c;

            // if the Opportunity Record ID is 'New to Blue'
            //avoid hardcoding ids in code newOpp.RecordTypeId == '0121N000001AR44QAG'

            if (newOpp.RecordTypeId == SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()
.get('New_to_Blue').getRecordTypeId()) {

                // if the related Account "Next Renewal Field" is not blank
                if (nextRenewalDate == null) {
                    newOpp.CloseDate = date.today() + 60;                              
                }
                if (nextRenewalDate != null) {
                    newOpp.CloseDate = nextRenewalDate - 60;
                }
            } 
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. I thought I was doing that by assigning newOpp.Account.Next_Renewal_Date__c to the variable nextRenewalDate. How should I be coding it to make it explicit?

Comment: @paulK I have updated the answer with code.

Comment: Oh nice. I'm working on this now. Will update with the best solution once I hammer out another bug.

Comment: Hey @Oleksandr, this isn't working and I'm getting no errors. After testing, I can confirm the trigger is not reaching the last two IF statements at all.

Comment: Could this be an issue of grabbing the AccountID but it being a 'before' trigger?

Comment: @paulK what is a correct api name of New to Blue opportunity record type?

Comment: You had it correct. It is New_to_Blue.

Comment: @paulK do you create opportunity with parent account and proper recordtype?

Comment: No. I am creating from the Opportunity and Account is a required field.

Comment: and yes, I am using the correct recordtype when creating the Opportunity.

Comment: @paulK ok. Can you make sure, that you are using the latest version of my answer, as I have recently made few changes to it?

Comment: Just tried it a couple times. Not working. Weird... I'm going to do a debug and see if I can find exactly where it is stopping but it is certainly not making it past the if statement about it being the correct record type.

Comment: @paulK debug nextRenewalDate

Comment: Still working on this but here is the update. I was able to determine that with the new code, it wasn't even running the trigger (i.e. no debug data provided). I have started to recreate the trigger now piece by piece (with it providing debug data). I think it may have to do with the placement of for (Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

Comment: I have rewritten some of the code since it wasn't working (mainly ordering). The trigger runs but doesn't get passed:

if(String.isNotBlank(newOpp.AccountId)) {
     Date nextRenewalDate = parentAccountById.get(newOpp.AccountID).Next_Renewal _Date__c;
     system.debug('nextRenewalDate assigned');

I don't see that debug in my logs, so it is stopping at that line. I checked the field on Account object and it is filled in with a date, so this should be running and at a minimum moving to the next line of code and showing the debug. 

Thoughts? 

Adding updated trigger to post.

Comment: Not the answer, as this was still causing issues. Posted solution to the original post.